# How to tell git to show diff of changes I did in last commit?

Tags: git, git-diff

With `git`, how do I see the changes in my last commit?

I mean I want to see a diff between my last commit and the commit previous to it. I know that I can see it on Github browser but I want to see this on terminal on my local commit history.

I know that I can do git diff between commits. So, I can do `git diff oldCommit...HEAD` to see the changes. But is there a command which can prevent me from having to copy `oldCommit` from `git log` which is cumbersome?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38481233/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+show+diff+changes+last+commit

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are a few ways to see that, but the simplest is probably just:

```
git show
```

The [git show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) command displays a formatted version of an object it git's database. Without any arguments, it shows `HEAD` - the currently checked out commit.

For a commit, its default output is the commit message and a diff to that commit's first parent - you can tweak that with the `--format` option.

Comment: All good answers but I choose this one because this is the simplest I could get. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Your most recent commit is `HEAD`, also known as `@`. The commit before anything is that thing suffixed with `~1` or simply `~`. So you could say

```
git diff @~ @
```

Comment: Nice! Do you mind explaining the command? `~1` is the `penultimate` commit and `@` is `HEAD`?

Comment: Haha, two minds with the same thought! See edit.

Comment: You can also use ^ instead of ~

Comment: @IMSoP well they aren't at all the same so that's a bit misleading.

Comment: @matt Well, `@~` and  `@^` are the same. `@~2` and  `@^2` aren't.